# Disk usage command not producing expected number of outputs

Tags: shell, command-line, disk-usage, syntax

I want to run disk usage command (`du`) on both a parent directory (to find the total of all its contents), and then additionally on one of its subdirectories only.

If I try to pass multiple paths into the `du` command with the *parent directory first* and then the *sub-directory second*, the output does **not** produce the result for the subdirectory:

```
du -s -B1 test_directory/ test_directory/sub_directory1/
20480   test_directory/
```

However, if I switch the order and put the *sub-directory first* and the the *parent directory second*, then it gives me both values as I would expect:

```
du -s -B1 test_directory/sub_directory1/ test_directory
12288   test_directory/sub_directory1/
8192    test_directory
```

Why does it work in this way? And is it documented somewhere?

Thanks!